# Datediff with dates in one column but only showing datediff compared to the next invoice

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

This is to understand how long it took the customer to pay a bill.
The datediff needs to be the next invoice to the payments

as Below example

```
ID  Type1         Amount        Date
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1    Invoice        38.16       2014-04-25     
1    Payment       -40.00       2014-03-23 
1    Invoice        40.86       2014-02-22 
1    Payment       -40.00       2014-02-21 
1    Invoice        42.21       2014-01-20


ID  Type1         Amount        Date             DATEDIFF 
---------------------------------------------------------
1    Invoice        38.16       2014-04-25     
1    Payment       -40.00       2014-03-23         29 
1    Invoice        40.86       2014-02-22 
1    Payment       -40.00       2014-02-21         32
1    Invoice        42.21       2014-01-20
```

Comment: Which DBMS (SQL Server, Postrgresql, Oracle etc) are you using? Which version if this DBMS are you using?

Comment: The solution for this type of problem can rely on the specific database and version of it that you are using; please update the question to include this information. (And also, remove the snippet tags - they're meant for html/js and not sql).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in many ways, one option is to use a correlated sub-query to get the date of the preceding row with item=invoice for all item=payment rows:

```
select 
  id, type1, amount, date,
  datediff(day, 
    (select top 1 date 
     from table1 
     where date <= t.date 
     and type1= 'Invoice'
     and t.type1='Payment' 
     order by date desc), 
    date) as diff
from table1 t;
```

This might not be the most efficient solution though.

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b1e32/12)

Or you could use an outer apply with the same effect: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b1e32/19